# What should I do for creating a Sports points application?

Tags: php, database, web-applications, vs-web-application-project

I'm thinking about developing a small application for keeping the score of a volleyball match. My idea is to have DB with the match info (points, sets etc) and one authorized person who has to login before is who changes the values. Other people have to be able to connect my webpage and see the real-time results. I thought about doing it with php in my server.

The only problem I have is to make that everytime the authorized person changes a value, the value has to be refreshed in the users webpage. Any idea?

I also thought about doing it with javarmi but my purpose is to make the application the most universal I can, so I think doing it as a web app is the best thing I can do.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of database? One that you have to poll or one that supports push notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax to refresh the content where the values are selected on regular basis